# How to pass azure tags to Packer CLI?

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, cicd, packer

I need to pass azure tags to resources created by packer.

[Documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/integrations/hashicorp/azure/latest/components/builder/arm) says that I need to use the `azure_tags` parameter, but its not very clear with the actual structure of the value.

The command

`packer build -var azure_tags=Tag1,"value1",Tag2,"value2"`

didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the values like this

```
packer build -var "azure_tags={Tag1=\"Value1\", Tag2=\"Value2\"}"
```